# Expand RAID array

Tags: server, raid

I'm pretty new to RAID, so please forgive my silly question.
I have an `Ubuntu Server 12.04 x64` installed on a pc having 4 hdds.
During RAID setup I selected RAID10 and (my ignorance) choose 2 active hdds and 2 spare hdds. I'm pretty sure it's not the optimal configuration and probably I should have selected 4 active hdds.

Running `cat /proc/mdstat` I get

```
md1 : active raid10 sdb2[1] sdd2[3](S) sdc2[2](S) sda2[0]
      948736 blocks super 1.2 2 near-copies [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid10 sdb1[1] sdd1[3](S) sdc1[2](S) sda1[0]
      311619072 blocks super 1.2 2 near-copies [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Is there a way I can convert spare disks to active disks?
I tried using `mdadm --grow /dev/md1 --raid-devices=4`, but got this answer

```
mdadm: RAID10 can only be changed to RAID0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot grow a RAID1+0 (it's not supported by mdadm).

From mdadm manpage:

> Grow (or shrink) an array, or otherwise reshape it in some way.
>   Currently supported growth options including changing the active size
>   of component devices and changing the number of active devices in
>   Linear and RAID levels 0/1/4/5/6, changing the RAID level between 0,
>   1, 5, and 6, and between 0 and 10, changing the chunk size and layout
>   for RAID 0,4,5,6, as well as adding or removing a write-intent bitmap.

Comment: So I cannot do anything else than keep current situation or restart from beginning, correct? :(

Comment: on very recent kernels (>3.0) you may be able to convert raid10 to raid0, but it's a risky business. Maybe someone can chime in on this.